# regex to match multiple IPAddress/domainnames delimited by a space

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find a regex where I am able to parse a test string `192.168.2.1 www.google.com 10.20.21.199` such as this where I `192.168.2.1`, `www.google.com` and `10.20.21.199` are valid ip addresses.

current regex to match multiple IPAddress/domainnames delimited by a `space` `rexp = /^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))(\s(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])))*$/`

test string `192.168.2.1 www.google.com 10.20.21.199`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If you are looking for multiple matches, you don't want to enforce the start of the string with `^`. I would recommend using an online tester until you are satisifed with the results and then deal with the programming afterwards: [Link](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Why are you complicating with these many alternatives if you just want the IP address and domain names, try this ```^(.\d+)+\s(.[a-z]+)+\s(.\d+)+$``` or just ```(.\d+)+\s(.[a-z]+)+\s(.\d+)+``` to get the result. If you have any more checks then update your question with complete details, currently the question is without any heads.

Comment: well the issue is you can't have a 257.900.856.123 IP address so that's why I think its that complicated

Comment: But if the list of data is known IP addresses you won't need the validation, you could do groups of `[0-9]{3}.`

Comment: How do you know that `www.google.com` is a valid IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (simplified) regex to seach for ip addresses as well as domainnames:

```
/((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))([ ]|$)|([\w-]+\.)+\w+([ ]|$)/g
```

The regex use the same pattern as yours for ip adresses except it uses the `'{3}'` quantifier to get the first three parts. Then it adds a check for domain names at the end (they can contain any number of sub domains).

Comment: Neither am I. But you can of course change that, if you want.

Comment: well that was easy to change.

Comment: your regex works 85% but I have some issues which I have highlighted in https://regex101.com/r/d4reA0/2 as the regex is also matching `www.google` which I think it should not but its ok to match `www.tn.good.au` which your regex does btwas its a perfectly valid hostname.

Comment: You're right, it has no knowledge about '.google' not being a valid Worldwide  domain. That would require a list of all main domains in the World.